# How to create view mongoose in Nestjs?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I would like create view in Nestjs

In example in mongoose:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
}, { autoCreate: false, autoIndex: false });
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const RedactedUser = mongoose.model('RedactedUser', userSchema);

await User.createCollection();

await RedactedUser.createCollection(...);
```

How to convert above example to setup in Nestjs?

I try it and cannot success:

```
 MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: UserSchema.name,
        useFactory: () => {
          const RedactedUser = mongoose.model('RedactedUser', UserSchema);

          RedactedCat.createCollection(...);

          return UserSchema;
        },
    
      },
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

The question says `create view` but your example suggests you are trying to create a collection.

If you are trying to make a collection then Nestjs handles this when you import the module with your schema and access the model.

here is a good place to start: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb